# Mysqli insert id: $mysqli->insert_id; or $stmt->insert_id?

Tags: php, mysqli, prepared-statement, insert-id

which one is the correct code in a prepared statement? `$ID_user=$mysqli->insert_id;`  or `$ID_user=$stmt->insert_id;` ?

```
$stmt = $mysqli->prepare("INSERT INTO users (first_name, last_name) VALUES (?   ,?)");
$stmt->bind_param("ss",$first_name,$last_name);     
if($stmt->execute())
{
     $ID_user=$mysqli->insert_id;  // or $ID_user=$stmt->insert_id;
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is absolutely no difference, you can use whatever you wish.